# comparison of two words in php always returning true

Tags: php, html

I am new in php and trying to compare two variable in it. I have tried like below but its always returning true even its not matching.

```
<?php
$messages ="test";
if ($messages = "Support" || "support") {
echo "matching";
}
else{
echo "not matching"; }

?>
```

Let me know if someone can help me for solve it.
Thanks

Comment: You're not testing for equality, you're assigning. Use double or triple equal signs. And you need to do the same on both sides of the `||`. `if ($messages === "Support" || $messages === "support")`

Comment: Keep in mind you can't do "half syntaxes" like that. `|| "support"` that means "if support" and "support" is something thus it returns true. https://3v4l.org/KgaKX you can use in_array to make a simpler syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a assignation.

On PHP, = sign are assignation one. For comparision, you need to use ==.

On your current operation, you're doing a comparision, and then, an assignation. "a" || "A" is equal to 1 (true). Then, you're assigning true to your variable $messages.

Change the line to:

```
if ($messages == "Support" || $messages == "support")
```

Comment: This is the fine...Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using = which is used for assignment, yo can use == or === (strict comparison) to compare strings.